# Can't Remove git Sub-Module

Tags: android, git, github, command-line

I am fairly new to git and had not really utilized the command-line interface until recently. I was trying to start a new private repository on github using Android Studio and made a mistake. I ran the command:
    `git remote add origin [github.com/location]`in two places, one of which was the root folder of the project, and one of which was subfolder containing the java class files. When I tried to add and commit all the files, it wouldn't include the subfolder, giving me the error: *fatal: Pathspec 'file' is in submodule 'app/src/...'* Before thinking through what I was doing, I tried removing the .git folder from the subfolder. There is no .gitmodules file in the .git folder in the root project folder, so there are no submodules to remove. I'm not sure if this is enough information to go off of so I'm sorry in advance if this sounds vague, but I was hoping someone could help me clear whatever is causing this so I can add this subfolder to the main project and commit it. Thank you!

FIXED:
I figured out that I needed to remove the subfolder and re-add it thusly:

```
git rm --cached dirname
git add dirname
```

I also had to get rid of the index.lock file in the base project .git folder in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check on the github repo if there is no conflict?

Do you try to commit locally or commit and push?

Did you try to clone the project on a another location?

If you use Windows or Mac,  I have a nice tool for git repository Source Tree

Comment: On github, is shows a folder within a folder icon for the subfolder, when I click on it, it shows one addition and one deletion, but no files. I have pushed, but it's when I go to the folder and try to manually 'add' it that I get the error.

Comment: Try to do a pull before. Maybe it is just a sync issue. Can you be more specific about the error ?